# How can I disable sessions for most of my Craft site?

Tags: config, session, cookies

We're running a craftcms-backed site that uses sessions only for the admin pages.

For a few reasons, we'd like to disable session logic for all other urls:

- the `Set-Cookie` header that craft uses to initiate a session makes responses uncacheable in our fronting cache layers
- the code path under `Craft\UserSessionService` is unnecessary overhead for most of our logic, and occasionally adds considerable latency

We've been using `HeaderHelper::removeHeader('Set-Cookie');` on a per-controller basis to turn off this behavior, but that only gets us so far - for example, `404` responses seem to try to initiate user sessions as well, before any of our custom logic can be used:

[image: This is a screenshot of newrelic transaction trace for a 404 response]
(This is a screenshot of newrelic transaction trace for a 404 response)

How can we get craftcms to stop trying to set these sessions?

I should note that we're looking into getting session storage out of the filesystem and into redis, which should also help - but most of the sessions we're keeping are meaningless, and I'd rather not keep track of them at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is going to be an easy way to do this in Craft 2, unfortunately.

In the upcoming Craft 3, we refactored the session logic so that a session will only get started on requests that actually *need* session, which is basically what you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent. As an side, this is going to make full page caching a lot easier from the server side.